# Adding to a list vs changing a list element

Tags: python

Take a look at the following code

```
testList = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
dummyList = testList
dummyList = dummyList + ["Hello"]
```

I was expecting the contents of testList to be changed as dummyList refers to testList and we just added a new element but this didn't happen. Now look at the following code.

```
testList = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
dummyList = testList
dummyList[0] = 'Hello'
```

In this code a change does take place in testList. Why is it that a change to dummyList changes the contents of testList in the second chunk of code and not the first?

Comment: Basically the same question as [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](//stackoverflow.com/q/575196), only without functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the `=` operator, you are making `testList` point to the same memory address as `dummyList`, so they are essentially the same object. This can be verified using `is`:

```
testList = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
dummyList = testList

>>> testList is dummyList
True
```

But when you re-assign it, it creates a new list, now not pointing to the same object:

```
dummyList = dummyList + ['hello']
>>> testList is dummyList
False
```

However, by making a change in place, such as by using `dummyList[0] = 'Hello'`, then it is simply making a change to the `dummyList`, which is still pointing to the same thing as `testList`. The difference is that there is no new assignment.

You can create a copy to avoid this altogether:

```
testList = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
dummyList = testList.copy()

>>> testList is dummyList
False
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first example you do *not* edit a list, you only construct a *new* list, and store that *new* list in the `dummyList` variable. But the old list never changed.

In the second example you *edit* the list. Since `dummyList` and `testList` refer to the *same* list, both variables indeed show the list with `'Hello'` as first element.

You *can* edit a list by adding an element, by using `.append(..)`:

```
ctestList = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
dummyList = testList
dummyList = dummyList.append("Hello")
```